# Theme Upgrade for an existing D7 site - block and config management

Tags: 7, theming, blocks

Working on developing a new Bootstrap theme for an existing D7 site.
**How can I make sure that the blocks are assigned to specific regions when the new theme is installed.**

Because I would be working in Dev where the theme config would be stored.(cannot update the prod db from dev).

Would really appreciate your inputs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that your new theme has the same regions defined in the info file as the current theme, otherwise the blocks will lose their assignment when the new theme is installed. The blocks are assigned in the database and they will stay assigned to those regions, as long as those regions are available.

Comment: thanks Rick. that makes sense.
As far as content-type and views config are concerned, the D7 way would be to move the theme files to production and re-do the configs right?

Comment: Ideally you want (hope) to do minimal re-config, and try have the site set up so that you can install themes without doing any reconfig, but I understand in some situations that is easier said than done and will vary from site to site. So the best thing to do is test it. Backup the site & db (easily done with a drush command), install the new theme (locally is safer rather than production) and see what happens. From there you will have an understanding of what reconfig will need to be done. Hope that helps.